# Remove the numbers from the chapters

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

I'm interested in keeping the chapter titles; I want to remove the large numbers, like the one in the image.
[image]

```
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{introduzione/introduzione.tex}
```

Comment: Please add a small, but compilable test file to your question in which we can see which class you use and if you use any package etc. which modify the appearance of the chapters.

Comment: i don't know how, sorry

Comment: Usually chapters without numbers are printed using `\chapter*{…}` instead of `\chapter{…}`. Depending on the class there could be additional commands like `\addchap{…}`.

Comment: That is not the standard layout so you have code to produce that large grey 1 that you have not shown, but are asking how to change...  Ifyou do not want a number at all use `\chapter*` but if you want it to be chapter 1, but with a smaller 1 you will need to show some example

Comment: Try with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.